# Methods to add and check elements in a Bloom Filter

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, comparative-review, concurrency

I have a working [Java implementation of Bloom Filter](https://github.com/srirammanoj/skynet/tree/bac3d34fb205f78fa0dcfccb95bb6d19667ad2ac).

These are the methods to addElement and check for an element.

```
private void addElement(byte[] element) {
    if (null == element) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    long hash1 = Integer.toUnsignedLong(Murmur3Hash.murmurhash3_x86_32(element, 0, element.length, filterParams.seed1));
    long hash2 = Integer.toUnsignedLong(Murmur3Hash.murmurhash3_x86_32(element, 0, element.length, filterParams.seed2));

    writeLock.lock();
    try {
        int offset = 0;
        long hash = hash1;
        int index;
        int mod;

        for (int i = 1; i <= filterParams.k; i++) {
            hash +=hash2;
            mod = ( int ) ( hash % filterParams.bucketLength );
            index = offset + mod;
            bitSet.set(index);
            offset += filterParams.bucketLength;
        }

        elementsAdded++;
    } finally {
        writeLock.unlock();
    }

}

public boolean containsElement(byte[] element) {
    if (null == element) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    long hash1 = Integer.toUnsignedLong(Murmur3Hash.murmurhash3_x86_32(element, 0, element.length, filterParams.seed1));
    long hash2 = Integer.toUnsignedLong(Murmur3Hash.murmurhash3_x86_32(element, 0, element.length, filterParams.seed2));

    readLock.lock();
    try {
        long hash = hash1;
        int offset = 0;
        int index;
        int mod;

        for (int i = 1; i <= filterParams.k; i++) {
            hash += hash2;
            mod = ( int ) ( hash % filterParams.bucketLength );
            index = offset + mod;
            offset += filterParams.bucketLength;
            if (!bitSet.get(index)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        readLock.unlock();
    }

    return true;
}
```

I was thinking of changing this code above like this.

```
private void addElement(byte[] element) {
    if (null == element) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    long hash1 = Integer.toUnsignedLong(Murmur3Hash.murmurhash3_x86_32(element, 0, element.length, filterParams.seed1));
    long hash2 = Integer.toUnsignedLong(Murmur3Hash.murmurhash3_x86_32(element, 0, element.length, filterParams.seed2));

    int offset = 0;
    long hash = hash1;
    int index;
    int mod;

    int[] indexArray = new int[filterParams.k];

    for (int i = 1; i <= filterParams.k; i++) {
        hash += hash2;
        mod = (int) (hash % filterParams.bucketLength);
        index = offset + mod;
        indexArray[i - 1] = index;
        offset += filterParams.bucketLength;
    }

    writeLock.lock();
    try {
        Arrays.stream(indexArray).forEach(bitSet::set);
        elementsAdded++;
    } finally {
        writeLock.unlock();
    }
}

public boolean containsElement(byte[] element) {
    if (null == element) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    long hash1 = Integer.toUnsignedLong(Murmur3Hash.murmurhash3_x86_32(element, 0, element.length, filterParams.seed1));
    long hash2 = Integer.toUnsignedLong(Murmur3Hash.murmurhash3_x86_32(element, 0, element.length, filterParams.seed2));

    long hash = hash1;
    int offset = 0;
    int index;
    int mod;
    boolean result;
    int[] indexArray = new int[filterParams.k];

    for (int i = 1; i <= filterParams.k; i++) {
        hash += hash2;
        mod = (int) (hash % filterParams.bucketLength);
        index = offset + mod;
        indexArray[i - 1] = index;
        offset += filterParams.bucketLength;
    }

    readLock.lock();
    try {
        result = Arrays.stream(indexArray).allMatch(bitSet::get);

    } finally {
        readLock.unlock();
    }

    return result;
}
```

My idea was to get more concurrency by minimizing the time spent inside the locks ( both the read and write locks ) for an increase in memory ( initializing an int[] array ) and reduced speed ( Instead of a single **'for'** loop, I now have an extra parallel iteration with the  **forEach**  method ).

Is this a viable tradeOff ?